# Need help assigning a (int) value to a combobox item (string)

Tags: c#, combobox

I'm creating a program with a dropdown box (combobox) in C#. I want to have the user select the item from the box, but I need to have an integer value assigned to the item so I can perform some math.

However, if I try to add a value like this it doesn't work.

```
this.selectquest.Items.AddRange(new object[] {
        "Level 51", int 5000000
        "Level 52", int 5000000
        "Level 53", int 5000000});
```

lol, now that may look ridiculous but yeah..

So I'm trying to figure out how to add a certain int value to those strings in the combo box so I can have the program perform math at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a custom class such as this:

```
class Level
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

then add your levels to the combobox:

```
this.selectquest.Items.AddRange(new Level[] {
    new Level() {Name = "Level 51", Value = 5000000},
    new Level() {Name = "Level 52", Value = 5000000},
    new Level() {Name = "Level 53", Value = 5000000}
});
```

Finally, in your SelectedIndexChanged, do

```
private void selectquest_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var v = selectquest.SelectedItem as Level;
    int x = v.Value;
}
```

EDIT: had forgotten to add:

```
selectquest.DisplayMember = "Name";
```

Cheers

Comment: Thanks for this. It didn't give me any errors but now all my string values in my combobox say:

`Name_of_form.level`

So the string values aren't showing properly.

Comment: @Advancin: you need to set `ValueMember` and `DisplayMember` properties of the `ComboBox`

Comment: See my update. The ValueMember is not really needed since my solution doesn't use the DataSource.

Comment: @mrlucmorin: yes `ValueMember` is not needed for your solution, sorry for wrong edit.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a class for that, for example:

```
public class Level
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
}
```

Create a list of Level's

```
var list = new List<Level>
        {
            new Level {Name = "Level 51", Number = 123214},
            new Level {Name = "Level 52", Number = 32343},
            new Level {Name = "Level 53", Number = 32343}
        };
```

Set `DataSource`, `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` properties

```
comboBox1.ValueMember = "Number";
comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
comboBox1.DataSource = list;
```

Then you can easily get the selected value in `SelectedIndexChanged` event, for example:

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     var selectedValue = (int)comboBox1.SelectedValue;
}
```

Comment: Doh ! you type fast :-)

Answer (score 0):

Just add them as strings to the combobox.  Then when the form is submitted you will have to convert them back to ints like:

```
int value = Convert.ToInt32(cbo.selectedValue);
```